# SFML cannot load image file no matter what I try

Tags: c++, image, sfml

I am trying a simple SFML project and it is giving me an error saying that it cannot load the image file. Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace sf;

int main() {
RenderWindow window(VideoMode(600, 600), "Chess");

system("dir");

Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("board.png");

Sprite s(texture);

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    //draw
    window.clear();
    window.draw(s);
    window.display();
}
}
```

I have tried every guide and fix for this problem I could find and not a single one of them has worked. Would anyone be able to help me? And yes, my image files are in the project directory. If it helps, I am using VS 2013.

Comment: Image file needs to be in **working** directory. Or (better) just use absolute paths.

Comment: Google "current working directory". Or, provide a full path to your file (possibly relative to the executable).

Comment: @VTT Absolute paths are bad. They break when you move your project or install in different locations. Better to use a path relative to the location of the executable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Relative paths break when you move stuff around just as easy. However absolute paths will refer to the same location regardless of process state which makes them easier to reason about. Your suggestion to use path relative to the location of the executable somehow implies working with absolute paths anyway.

Comment: @VTT I tried an absolute path. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Then most likely you've specified incorrect path. Or used wrong escape sequence for \

Comment: ***my image files are in the project directory*** If you did not change the default settings this should be the correct folder in Visual Studio. Maybe your files are actually named `board.png.png` and you don't see that because windows hides the extension on known types?

Comment: No it just flat out doesn't work, I used / and \, made sure it was the right path, and specified my project directory in project settings. I have no idea what's wrong. All the common fixes don't work.

Comment: You should check the return value from loadFromFile() to see if the file was read.

Comment: Ok @drescherjm thank you that worked. I had it named as board.png, which would have made it board.png.png.

Comment: I recommend on turning off the setting in windows file explorer that hides extensions for known types it adds more confusion than it helps.